# can't login laptop ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, login

It happened a few times to me already.

It is an Azerty keyboard, set on [french (legacy, alternative)].

I have letters + figures to type.

If I use capslock for my numbers, it doesn't work, password is not recognized.

Now, if I use SHIFT key instead of capslock, it works.

So, obviously, there is a bug.

Any solution to fix this for once and for all?

Hint: I tried virtual keyboard: numbers are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug.

NUMLOCK and CAPSLOCK are NOT enabled by default  hence  using them without setting first which may not be possible on that motherboard/configuration they are useless in that case..... try looking in BIOS for a NUMLOCK / keypad enabled on boot setting enable it if there.